# Solving the integral $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(\sin[2n+1]t) \cdot \frac{\sin(t)-t}{sin(t) \cdot t}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, definite-integrals

How should I solve this integral ?:

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\left(\vphantom{\Large A}\left[2n + 1\right]t\right)\,
{\sin\left(t\right) - t \over t\sin\left(t\right)}\,{\rm d}t
$$
How can I use Fourier coefficients ?.

Comment: Is $\large n$ an integer ?.

Comment: $n$ is a natural

Comment: You've already asked this exact question [before](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702790/definite-integral-problem).

Comment: but I want to use Fourier coefficients

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin\bigg([2n+1]t\bigg)\cdot \Big(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\sin(t)}\Big) \mathrm{d}t$

I noticed that function $\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\sin(t)}$ is almost everywhere continuous so I used Riemann's Lema. 
The answer is $0$. Is it right?

Comment: No. Just check the $n=0$ case for a counter example.

Comment: ok, but $n \to \infty$